# ImportError: cannot import name ConnectionPool

Tags: python, python-2.7, ckan

While testing my application using nosetests. I am getting some error related to import error:

The command I am using on Linux CLI is: `nosetests -m test_file`

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name ConnectionPool)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/tests/views/test_admin.py", line 10, in <module>
    import ckan.tests.helpers as helpers
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/tests/helpers.py", line 32, in <module>
    import rq
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .connections import (Connection, get_current_connection, pop_connection,
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/connections.py", line 7, in <module>
    from redis import StrictRedis
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/redis.py", line 15, in <module>
    from redis import ConnectionPool, Redis
ImportError: cannot import name ConnectionPool
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
pyutilib.component.core.pca: DEBUG: Creating PluginEnvironment 'pca'
pyutilib.component.core.<default>: DEBUG: Creating PluginEnvironment '<default>'
pyutilib.component.core.<default>: DEBUG: Pushing environment '<default>' on the PluginGlobals stack
pyutilib.component.core.pca: DEBUG: Pushing environment 'pca' on the PluginGlobals stack
pyutilib.component.core.pca: DEBUG: Pushing environment 'pca' on the PluginGlobals stack
pyutilib.component.core.pca: INFO: Adding service IgnorePluginPlugins to environment pca
pyutilib.component.core.pca: INFO: Adding service IgnorePluginPlugins to environment pca
pyutilib.component.core.pca: DEBUG: Popping environment 'pca' from the PluginGlobals stack
passlib.utils.compat: DEBUG: loaded lazy attr 'BytesIO': <built-in function StringIO>
passlib.registry: DEBUG: registered 'pbkdf2_sha512' handler: <class 'passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha512'>
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
```

I had a searched for it and found that my redis.py is I guess being accessed before the redis module.

For more reference: https://gist.github.com/camfindlay/a8c080435960fe87388474839418f0f0#file-gistfile1-txt-L154

So, for this I had set my **PYTHONPATH** and **PATH**.

The Output of echo $PATH is as follows:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin:/home/ubuntu64/bin:/home/ubuntu64/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/bin/python
```

But I am still not able to resolve the issue.

**Update 1:** 
Attaching the error logs appearing on screen:

[image]

Comment: Did you name anything `redis` in your project folder?

Comment: I have a file named redis.py in /lib/ folder

Comment: That might get imported instead of the `redis` library.

Comment: Yes, But how do I assure that it doesn't happens, I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file at `/ckan/lib/redis.py` is conflicting with your redis package.

Can you use a virtual environment and install all dependencies?

After you are done with it, you can use following code -

```
from .redis import *  #For importing something from your redis.py
from redis import ConnectionPool  #For importing from redis module
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Hi @yadavankit , The file is present at location "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/redis.py" , it already has - "from redis import ConnectionPool, Redis" written in it.

Comment: @KushagraSrivastava have made edits. Can you use a virtual environment?

Comment: Also,changing the name of the file redis.py to redis_test.py still shows the same error. yes, @yadavankit , venv is ON.

Comment: @KushagraSrivastava can you make another venv and install redis in it, activate it and import the same in ipython?